# How to parse string date to UK culture in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, culture

I am trying to write a helper function to format date based on the culture. In the database date is being saved as **en-US** culture. Now, in my helper function, i may need to parse **DateTime** or **String** type date and that's why **dynamic val** as parameter.

But, in case of passing string and for parsing the date to culture like '**en-GB**' i.e. for **UK** culture, date can not be parsed.

**My code:**

```
    public static string FormatDate(dynamic val, bool isShowTime = false)
    {
        string date = "";
        DateTime dateValue;
        string value = val == null ? "" : val.ToString();
        string culture = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CULTURE"] as String;
        if (culture == null) { culture = "en-US"; }
        CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
        if (value != "")
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(value, new CultureInfo(culture), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue) && Convert.ToDateTime(value, new CultureInfo(culture)) != Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1900", new CultureInfo(culture)))
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                if (isShowTime)
                {
                    date = dateValue.ToShortDateString() + " " + dateValue.ToString("hh:mm tt"); ;
                }
                else
                {
                    date = dateValue.ToShortDateString();
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

        return date;
    }
```

Let's say the date is "**11/27/2019**" (**MM/DD/YYYY**) and the culture is "**en-GB**",

`DateTime.TryParse(value, new CultureInfo(culture), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue)`

returns **false**. It should parse as "**DD/MM/YYYY**" i.e. "**27/11/2019**"

What am i missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: datetime should be stored as datetime, not as string ;-)

Comment: Yes, if you take Stefan's comment, all of this conversion logic just goes away - always use the most appropriate data type or you will run into problems. For example, if you store dates as strings, you lose the ability to order them easily.

Comment: For some dates, date is being stored as datetime in database but for some dates is being stored as string. Is there any way to parse the date string? DateTime.TryParse() should expect datetime as parameter. Don't know why they are expecting string here.

Comment: Should i convert it to DateTime and then ToString() like below and then pass it to the DateTime.TryParse().

  var date = "11/27/2019";
  var parsedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString();

Comment: Yes. Ideally your data would be stored as a `Date` and not a `String` however since you are working with a String. DateTime.TryParse() is not going to convert from one format to another (except if using the `AdjustToUTC` DateTimeStyles option). What your code is attempting to do is see if the US formatted date string can be parsed as a valid GB date (which in this case it cannot, hence the false result).  

What you would need to do is convert the string to a date and then format that date however you like (en-GB).

Comment: @Anu6is, you are suggesting to do this right?  var date = "11/27/2019"; var parsedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString(); and then parse the converted date in DateTime.TryParse(parsedDate)

Comment: DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue);
dateValue.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture)))); ... Preference being you can check if the TryParse() was successful or not.